# Separator character for terminology and definitions section?

Tags: punctuation, terminology, typing

If I write a section of terminology and definitions in academic writing, which is the correct unicode character for the "-"? Is it the dash or is it a hyphen? For example:

> CPU - Central Processing Unit. It is the center of the computer and
>   performs calculations.

Should I write my section terminology and definitions similar to the above or can I improve it? More examples

> State space - The set of values which a process can take.
>
> RS-232 - Recommended standard 232 (as recommended by IEEE). It is a
>   serial interface for UART

The complete list is [available online](https://goo.gl/pV9fY7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is an official rule for this, but in all the examples I found online, a dash was used.

On a side note, a section of terminology and definitions is often referred to as a glossary.